# CardsLib and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer, cardslib

I have been at this for quite a few days now and I cannot for the life of me figure this out so that's why I came here!

Right now I am trying to get `CardsLib` ([GitHub Link Here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)) to work in a fragment. I am currently using a Navigation Drawer setup and every time I think i get it working as soon as it opens it crashes.

The reason it crashes is because when `CardsLib` goes to get the context (getActivity().getApplicationContext() it returns null and it throws and error on this piece of code `cardView.setCard(card);`

Now previously `card` is initialized as `Card card = new Card(getContext());` which makes sense that the context is null.

If anyone could give me an example of `CardsLib` in a fragment that would be much help.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to use the CardView provided by Google in the new support library provided with the preview of Android L. In this way you have a "real" library and support even in the future.

Comment: I didn't even know that existed. So much for me doing my homework. I'll have to check it out. Thanks!

Comment: You can't compare them. IT depends on what you need.
CardView provided by Google is just a FrameLayout. Cardslib provided some built-in features over it.
If you only need a layout, use the google cardView.
In anycase, cardslib will work with the new Google CardView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
Card card = new Card(getActivity());
```

in `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
Context context = getActivity();
```

so for all the "this" inside the code sample, I replace it with "context" above. Hope this helps.